# Trying to configure & mount 4 Virtual hard drives as RAID-5 volume in Virtual Ubuntu Server 20.04 under VMWare

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, raid, vmware

I have a VMWare server running Ubuntu Server 20.04.  Things are working great for the most part.  For some reason, I'm having troubles mounting a RAID 5 volume that contains 4 1TB hard drives as a 3TB volume.  I've tried quite a few things, including CLI admin, Webmin methods, etc. and just can't seem to get the volume mounted.  Any ideas and / or direction sincerely appreciated!